# Options to debug ssl handshake on windows

Tags: windows, ssl, handshake

I have an issue with a windows server where an application pointing at a https end point fails with a:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.
Actually it used to succeed but now it does not.
This is within an enterprise so the https is pointing to a private IP address.

What options do I have to investigate the handshake failure from the windows server?
openssl is not available on windows.
I have googled wireshark and  Microsoft network Monitor.
Not sure I will get the go ahead to deploy either of these 2 options.
Any suggestions?

TIA

Tony

Comment: Wireshark, sslyze, looking for log messages and a deeper knowledge of the TLS protocol and what can go wrong. See also http://noxxi.de/howto/ssl-debugging.html